# using variables in controls from Form_load

Tags: c#

I declared my variable in `Form_load` so that it's preloaded and I plan to have these variables used and edited by some events, but I can't call them outside of the controls.

Am I doing it wrong? If yes, how should I do it?

[image: 1]

Comment: Please don't post images of code. Post the code as text.

Comment: @Loocid - Please post as an answer.

Comment: I'd suggest changing `Convert.ToString(totaldue);` to `$"{totaldue}";`.

Comment: Please, before writing any code with an object oriented language learn the base of the class definition and usage

Answer (score 1):

You need to make that variable a member of the class. Currently it just lives in the `Form1_Load` method. Add `private int totaldue;` to the top of your class and remove it from the form load.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `totaldue` is only defined in the scope of the method `Form1_Load`. You have to define that variable outside to access it from another scope.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    private int totaldue;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    
    public void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comboBoxl.Items.Add("Movie 1");
        comboBoxl.Items.Add("Movie 5");
        comboBoxl.Items.Add("Movie 4");
        comboBoxl.Items.Add("Movie 3");
        comboBoxl.Items.Add("Movie 2");
    }
    
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(totaldue);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, and sorry for bothering to ask such a question, the Pandemic really messed up our Curriculum and we had to rush everything for the end of the academic year.